# How can I convert a cv::Mat to a gray scale in OpenCv?

Tags: c++, variables, opencv, grayscale

How can I convert a cv::Mat to a gray scale?

I am trying to run drawKeyPoints func from opencv, however I have been getting an Assertion Filed error. My guess is that it needs to receive a gray scale image rather than a color image in the parameter.

```
void SurfDetector(cv::Mat img){
vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
cv::Mat featureImage;

cv::drawKeypoints(img, keypoints, featureImage, cv::Scalar(255,255,255) ,cv::DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);

cv::namedWindow("Picture");
cv::imshow("Picture", featureImage);
```

}

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Using the C++ API, the function name has slightly changed and it writes now:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

cv::Mat greyMat, colorMat;
cv::cvtColor(colorMat, greyMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

The main difficulties are that the function is in the **imgproc** module (not in the core), and by default cv::Mat are in the Blue Green Red (BGR) order instead of the more common RGB.

**OpenCV 3**

Starting with OpenCV 3.0, there is yet another convention. 
Conversion codes are embedded in the namespace `cv::` and are prefixed with `COLOR`.
So, the example becomes then:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

cv::Mat greyMat, colorMat;
cv::cvtColor(colorMat, greyMat, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```

As far as I have seen, the included file path hasn't changed (this is not a typo).

Comment: Under OpenCV 3, the conversion type constant has been changed to COLOR_BGR2GRAY

Comment: Thanks, I'll update the answer. OpenCV 3 is rolling out soon, it will be useful.

Comment: @sansuiso Thanks, do you know how I can get a grayscaled image with the same channels as the input image? currently this method, converts the whole image into 1 channeled balck and white image. what should I do to just make my image black and white and also not 1 channeled!

Comment: Ok, I guess I found it```cv::cvtColor(img, greyMat, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

cv::cvtColor(greyMat, greyMat, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);```

Answer (score 2):

May be helpful for late comers.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc != 2) {
    cout << "Usage: display_Image ImageToLoadandDisplay" << endl;
    return -1;
}else{
    Mat image;
    Mat grayImage;

    image = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR);
    if (!image.data) {
        cout << "Could not open the image file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        int height = image.rows;
        int width = image.cols;

        cvtColor(image, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);


        namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        imshow("Display window", image);

        namedWindow("Gray Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        imshow("Gray Image", grayImage);
        cvWaitKey(0);
        image.release();
        grayImage.release();
        return 0;
    }

  }

}
```