# OpenCV distance transform error

Tags: c++, opencv

I ran the answer from this question [Blending does not remove seams in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315904/blending-does-not-remove-seams-in-opencv) but I am getting

OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats source image must be 8UC1 and the distance map must be 32fc1 or 8uC1 in case of simple L1 distance transform>> in unknown function.

Why am I getting this error?Does it have to do with my inputs??

Answer (score 0):

The doc of opencv on the distance tranform states that the input image must be "8-bit, single-channel " (CV_8UC1) and that the output image will be "32-bit floating-point, single-channel" (CV_32FC1) http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html .

It is likely that your input image is not CV_8UC1. To get one, you may use a comparison operator such as `>=`, as in the sample code on the distance transform distrans.cpp ( in the source, in `opencv/samples/cpp` ).

```
 Mat edge = gray >= edgeThresh;
```

`edge` will be the input, `gray` may be a grayscale image and `edgeThresh` is an integer (=100).

To get a grayscale image, you may use first : [How can I convert a cv::Mat to a gray scale in OpenCv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344246/how-can-i-convert-a-cvmat-to-a-gray-scale-in-opencv)

```
 cv::cvtColor(colorMat, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Bye,