# Android jpeg pictureCallback to grayscale Opencv Mat

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, android-ndk

I'm trying to decode android pictureCallback to grayscale mat:

Firstly I tried to use rawPicture callback but always I get null pointer.

```
 mCamera.takePicture(null, mPicture, null);
```

JpegCalback gives me not null byte[] array, but cvtColor conversion doesn't work.

```
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
```

My preview callback is this

```
Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"picture taken",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        int res=JniManager.setImage(data,m_width,m_height);
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
};
```

c++ JNI function:

```
    Java_pidaas_vicomtech_org_facerec_viulib_JniManager_setImage(JNIEnv *env,
                                                    jobject instance,
                                                    jbyteArray image,
                                                    jint width,
                                                    jint height)
     jbyte* _yuv  = env->GetByteArrayElements(image, 0);
     int len = env->GetArrayLength (image);
     unsigned char* buf = new unsigned char[len];
     env->GetByteArrayRegion (image, 0, len, reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(buf));
     Mat rawData (cv::Size(width,height), CV_8UC3, buf );
            cv::Mat test =imdecode(rawData,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
            cv::Mat grey;
            cv::cvtColor(test, grey, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            bool flag = imwrite("/sdcard/graypg.jpg", grey);
    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(image, _yuv, 0);
}
```

I have found some answers but none of them works.

- [What format is for Android camera with raw pictureCallback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226531/what-format-is-for-android-camera-with-raw-picturecallback/14367899#14367899)
- [How can I convert a cv::Mat to a gray scale in OpenCv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344246/how-can-i-convert-a-cvmat-to-a-gray-scale-in-opencv/10346021#10346021)
- [opencv read jpeg image from buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727267/opencv-read-jpeg-image-from-buffer)

I write image on sdcard because of testing, but it writes an empty image of 0 bytes.

So, anybody knows how do I should get jpeg pixels as gray format?

Comment: What value contains len? I think I have a similary problem in the past because getarraylenght sometimes returns 0, the correct len could be calculate int multiplication of width x height

Comment: You are right, the len is 0, I didn't pay attention because the image was corrupt but, I couldn't see any SIGSEV error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the getarraylenght is not working propertly and is returning 0. I usually use lenght as width x height, parameters provided to calculate the array size. That will copy propertly the data from camera buffer to memory.

Warning: If something is wrong with the size, you will have an Signal 11 exception!